# axios.put save as a string

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, axios

if I try to use axios.put to save a string, it will give an error 400: Invalid data; couldn't parse JSON object, array, or value.

For example:

```
axios.put('firebase/url/example.json', "some string")
```

But if I use a integer, it will work perfectly:

```
axios.put('firebase/url/example.json', 200)
```

How can I save a string using put?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase will try to parse "some string" using a `JSON.parse`-like function.
If you try it yourself, you will not be able to parse this:

```js
JSON.parse("some string")
```

But if you encode the string properly, you will see it gets wrapped in more quotes:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify("some string"))
console.log("some string")
// will output:
// 1. "some string"
// 2. some string
```

The [Firebase API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put) highlight this with this example:

```
curl -X PUT -d '"Alan Turing"' \
  'https://docs-examples.firebaseio.com/rest/saving-data/fireblog/users/alanisawesome/name.json'
```

So all you need to do is properly parse the data beforehand:

```
axios.put('firebase/url/example.json', JSON.stringify("some string"))
```

The reason `200` works, is that it's a single number which can be directly read by a JSON parser.